# Add icons Toolbar and TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add 4 icons on my `Toolbar` and a `TextView` that I want to act as a `Title` this is my `xml`

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar" />        
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toolbar" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvToolbar"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_17sdp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But the output isn't what I'm expecting, I'd like to get a `Toolbar` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwkje.png), but it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idHNa.jpg).

And when I launch the application it appears a `ToolbatTitle` that I think it's the name of the APP how do I quit this and use the `TextView` one?

Comment: that's totally against Google's Design Guidelines. I don't think you'll be able to do it using the Toolbar class. Try using a LinearLayout Instead and setting the same height as a toolbar would have.

Comment: When Toolbar didn't exist I did something similiar with ActionBar... I want to know how to do it now with Toolbar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the official [design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars). You should not have icons to the left of the title other than the up action.

Instead of inserting the `ImageView`'s into the activity's xml create an xml menu resource and implement it by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_resource_you_created, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html) and more specifically [this](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) for more info.

---

**EDIT:** If you really want to do this regardless of the guidelines I would probably just put a `LinearLayout` or similar in the xml, make sure it's at the top of the parent and set these attributes:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
```

Again, I do not recommend this nor can I guarantee it as a legitimate workaround, but I'm pretty sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I guess he wants to add a Title and 2 imageViews on left of it and 2 more on right... if you put those imageviews on the menu it will appear on the right side.

Comment: Right but doing so is against the material design guidelines which is why `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar` do not accommodate the task.

Comment: so it's not possible to do it now?I thought it was

Comment: @YoungCoconutCode But if I just want to add an ImageView on center of the Toolbar? Without title how do I do this?

Comment: @Pedro Please see the edit in the above answer. Hope it helps.